# Cannot configure timer to 10µs on STM32F401 device

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, arm, cortex-m4

I'm using an STM32F401CCU6 microcontroller and am trying to generate a timer interrupt of 10 us with TIMER3.

The timer is a update event timer. The formula I'm using is:

`Update_event = TIx_CLK/((PSC + 1)*(ARR + 1))`.

I'm confused whether I should be using 84 MHz for my Clock Frequency or 42 MHz.

Below, I've given my clock configuration. Secondly, I got my ARR value of (840-1) and the Prescaler as 1 for a 10 µs timer. Is this incorrect?

Also, I'm using the Keil development software and when I run the code, with a breakpoint on my `TIM3_IRQHandler` function, then the timer value is always different when the code reaches the interrupt. Even if my initial timer values are incorrect, the timer value should be 1 when the interrupt is generated.

My code is:

```
SystemClock_Config Function :



> void SystemClock_Config(void)
> 
> {
> 
>   RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};   RCC_ClkInitTypeDef
> RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
> 
>   /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage   */  
> __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();   __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);   /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters 
> * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.   */   RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;  
> RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;  
> RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;  
> RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;  
> RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;   RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 168;  
> RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;  
> RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;   if
> (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)   {
>     Error_Handler();   }   /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks   */   RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType =
> RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
>                               |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;  
> RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;  
> RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;  
> RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;  
> RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
> 
>   if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) !=
> HAL_OK)   {
>     Error_Handler();   } }


Timer3 Function : 


> static void MX_TIM3_Init(void) {
> 
>   /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 0 */
> 
>   /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 0 */
> 
>   TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};  
> TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
>   
> 
>   /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 1 */
> 
>   /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 1 */   htim3.Instance = TIM3;  
> htim3.Init.Prescaler = 1;//;   htim3.Init.CounterMode =
> TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;   htim3.Init.Period = 839;  
> htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
> 
>   htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
> 
>   if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)   {
>     Error_Handler();   }   sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
> 
>   if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) !=
> HAL_OK)   {
>     Error_Handler();   }   sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
> 
>   sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
> 
>   if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) !=
> HAL_OK)   {
>     Error_Handler();   }
> 
>   /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 2 */
> 
>   HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
> 
>   /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 2 */
> 
> 
> }
```

[image]

Can someone please point out my mistake? I've been wrestling with it for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution: there wasn't any problem with the initialization. The problem was that in the stm32f4 series and beyond, you have to set freeze bits in the DBGMCU_APB1_FZ register.

This is used if you are in debug mode and want to freeze core clock for counters like timers, because even when you halt, the timer is still running. I've seen many having the same problem but non have ever actually proposed this solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you provided, your TIM3 clock frequency is 84 MHz, as it's connected to APB1. (see *"APB1 Timer clocks"* box)

By default, timers continue to run even when your code hits to a breakpoint during debug session. You can force them to stop using relevant bits in DBGMCU registers.

Comment: is my timer of 10us calculation correct ,for the prescaler and autoreload registers ?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed , Values are correct, but normally PSC = (1 - 1) and ARR = (840 - 1) needs to be loaded into the hardware registers. I'm not sure how the HAL libraries handle them. I recommend activating a PWM output and checking it with a logic analyzer.

Comment: okay , got it , but Im using Keil , my main problem is , first time timer interrupt is generated i get a timer count of 14us , then second time interrupt is generated the timer value is 0.5us , third time its 12us . why is this happening ?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed , First time may be different because PSC register is updated only after an update event. You may trigger it manually using EGR register. But how do you measure these periods? It's very hard unless you use a logic analyzer. And remember, your timers continue to run even when your main execution stops during a debug session, unless you configure it otherwise.